# issue in matching the size of a box to mobile css bootsrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm facing an issue in matching the size of a  box to mobile(using bootstrap)
I have got 3 boxes, number 1 and 2 are images and number 3 has text,
and it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvbP4.png)

when I resize the screen to mobile size this is what happens(box number 3 is higher or in some devices shorter than box number 2, like here:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlr5R.png)

I need it to look like that (box number 3 in the same height as 2):[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS0Tg.png)

I tried to set max height and min hight to box3 but this is not the solution because it doesn't match to all the devices.

html:

```
 <section id="carousel-section">

  <div class="container-fluid">

     <div class="row feature">
         <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-8 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
             <div class="carousel-margin">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel1 slide container-carousel" data-
 ride="carousel1">
  <!-- Indicators -->
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>

 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="images/dragon_hunter_pic.png" alt="dragon_hunter_pic" 
   id="mainImage1" >
</div>

 </div>

    </div>
         </div>   
         </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 ">

       <div class="women-margin">
  <img src="images/women_3.png" alt="live" id="women-eyes1" >
            </div>
            </div>




  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-7 col-xs-7 col-sm-7 ">

      <div class="yellow-box">


      <h2 id="change_h2">THE DRAGON HUNTER</h2>
            <br/>
            <p id="change_p"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
       adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
        dolor aliqua. </p>

         </div>


      </div>

  </div>
 </div>

  </section>
```

this is the problematic box, box number 3:

```
    <div class="yellow-box">
```

css:

```
  .yellow-box{
 position: relative;

 display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

    min-height: 204px;
 margin-top:150px;
background-color: #e6ff00;
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;  


   }
```

this is box number 2:

```
  .women-margin{
  margin: -1px -15px -2px -17px;
position: relative;
display: block;
padding-right: 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flex on the row. Does not work in some older browsers.

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

See: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Use media query maybe for mobile view only:

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .row-eq-height {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display:         flex;
  }

}
```

This is a sample you can try, flex makes columns equal height, but actually it is a contradiction to use Bootstrap and flex together. But just trying to fix your specific code:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
  .yellow-box{
 position: relative;

 display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

    min-height: 204px;
 margin-top:150px;
background-color: #e6ff00;
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;  


   }
.women-margin{
  margin: -1px -15px -2px -17px;
position: relative;
display: block;
padding-right: 0;
   }
  .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
</style>
<section id="carousel-section">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row feature">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
                <div class="carousel-margin">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel1 slide container-carousel" data-
                    ride="carousel1">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="images/dragon_hunter_pic.png" alt="dragon_hunter_pic" id="mainImage1" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5">
                <div class="women-margin">
                    <img src="images/women_3.png" alt="live" id="women-eyes1" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-7">
                <div class="yellow-box">
                    <h2 id="change_h2">THE DRAGON HUNTER</h2>
                    <br/>
                    <p id="change_p"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
                    dolor aliqua. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to add that but then it disappears box 2  and 3 in mobile, can you please show me how to combine this in the code?